Подключение google sheets к kotlin
Требуется подключить гугл таблицы к коотлин, для получения и изменения данных. Как это сделать?
На питоне есть библиотека gspread, может есть что-то подобное на kotlin?
В интернете пока что, ничего особо не нашел :(

Есть специальный Google Sheets API, там есть примеры на Java, если вам нравится Kotlin переводите код.
